# Micronaut does not generate OpenAPI YAML with query parameters

Tags: swagger, openapi, micronaut

Running latest version of Micronaut (1.0.3) and including Swagger dependencies generates the OpenAPI YAML file. However, it does not include the parameters for query string even when supplying Swagger's `@Parameter`.

```
package hello;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;

@io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
public class Controller {   
    @Get(uri = "/hello")
    public String hello(@Parameter(name = "name",
                description = "Name of person to greeted") String name) {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, although I expect that suppressing @Parameter should work, I managed to make it work adding `in=ParameterIn.QUERY`.

Moreover, looking at Micronaut's source code using `@QueryValue` should also work.